# Pandas - create new column where rows match

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to create a new column in pandas that matches row values  based on the same condition. I'm trying to turn a dependent variable into an independent variable.

In the sample dataframe below (taken from the actual dataset), each row is separated by the value `test_name` and by time period, 'tp'. I want to create a new column `intensity_value`, where the values for tp are equal and place the new column where the `test_value` is 'PANAS'

For instance, in the dataframe, the third row has a 'PANAS' value of 35 and an intensity value of 50 in the 7th row. Both rows have the same id (73) and time period, w3s1. The ideal dataframe would have a new column in the 3rd row, `intensity_value` of 50.

Code is below to create a dataframe from a dictionary. I haven't been able to find any examples online that create new columns by similar row values.

Thanks  for any help and please let me know if I can make this question easier to answer.

```
df = {'trial_id': {73: 79, 300: 79, 515: 79, 715: 79, 2541: 79, 2673: 79, 2810: 79, 2960: 79}, 'tp': {73: 'w1s1', 300: 'w2s1', 515: 'w3s1', 715: 'w4s1', 2541: 'w1s1', 2673: 'w2s1', 2810: 'w3s1', 2960: 'w4s1'}, 'test_name': {73: 'PANAS', 300: 'PANAS', 515: 'PANAS', 715: 'PANAS', 2541: 'intensity', 2673: 'intensity', 2810: 'intensity', 2960: 'intensity'}, 'value': {73: 25.0, 300: 30.0, 515: 35.0, 715: 34.0, 2541: 0.0, 2673: 0.0, 2810: 50.0, 2960: 0.0}} 

pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
```

Comment: It is very easy. Use from numpy.select method. You can pass conditions and choice list and default value for new column

Comment: show us how your expected results should look like

Answer (score 0):

just join/merge the same df with itself

```
import pandas as pd
df = {'trial_id': {73: 79, 300: 79, 515: 79, 715: 79, 2541: 79, 2673: 79, 2810: 79, 2960: 79}, 'tp': {73: 'w1s1', 300: 'w2s1', 515: 'w3s1', 715: 'w4s1', 2541: 'w1s1', 2673: 'w2s1', 2810: 'w3s1', 2960: 'w4s1'}, 'test_name': {73: 'PANAS', 300: 'PANAS', 515: 'PANAS', 715: 'PANAS', 2541: 'intensity', 2673: 'intensity', 2810: 'intensity', 2960: 'intensity'}, 'value': {73: 25.0, 300: 30.0, 515: 35.0, 715: 34.0, 2541: 0.0, 2673: 0.0, 2810: 50.0, 2960: 0.0}} 

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(df)
df2 = df1.loc[df1['test_name'] == 'PANAS']
df1 = df1.loc[df1['test_name'] == 'intensity']
df3 = df2.merge(df1, how='inner', left_on='tp', right_on='tp')
df3 = df3[['tp', 'test_name_x', 'value_x', 'test_name_y', 'value_y']]
print(df3)
```

here is the result:

```
tp test_name_x  value_x test_name_y  value_y
0  w1s1       PANAS     25.0   intensity      0.0
1  w2s1       PANAS     30.0   intensity      0.0
2  w3s1       PANAS     35.0   intensity     50.0
3  w4s1       PANAS     34.0   intensity      0.0
```

you can change the column names as you like